# How to construct a 5x5 matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

How can I construct a matrix with 5 rows and 5 columns?

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

[[float("inf")]*len(lst) for k in range (len(lst))]
```

gives me `[[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf]]`

How can I change the parameters so I can get a 5x5 matrix?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want a matrix that you can access `matrix[row][column]` to get elements from it? Do you want to populate the matrix with some information? Right now you have nested lists such that you can access elements inside (and retrieve a certain "inf") using `matrix[row][column]` (depending on how you look at it) to access a particular element, it's just printed out all in one line.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are using the `lst` variable, but what you need is something approaching this:

```
def matrix(x,y,initial):
    return [[initial for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
```

Which gives:

```
> print matrix(5,5,float('inf'))
[[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf]]

> my_matrix = matrix(2,2,0)
> print my_matrix
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
> my_matrix[0][2] = 2
> print my_matrix
[[0, 2], [0, 0]]
```

A matrix in most languages is just a set of nested arrays. If you need anything more than that you might want to make a custom class.

Comment: I was trying to show why they didn't need to use `range(len(lst))` and how to access elements in the "matrix".

Answer (score 0):

What you have already *is* a 5x5 matrix. Just represented as a list of rows. If you want something that "looks" like a matrix, maybe you'll like numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.full((5, 5), np.inf)
array([[ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Simplest way I Found to  Create
5x5 matrix with row values ranging from 0 to 4

```
arr = np.arange(0,5)

arr = np.tile(arr,(5,1))

arr
```

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,5).reshape(5,1)

print(x)

Comment: Is that answer correct to solve the question Create a 5x5 matrix with row values ranging from 0 to 4.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).